# Are there any decentralized examples of AI systems with blockchain technology?

Tags: reference-request, multi-agent-systems, blockchain

Has there been any attempts to deploy AI with blockchain technology?

Are there any decentralized examples of AI networks with no central point of control with AI nodes acting independently (but according to a codified set of rules) creating, validating and storing the same shared decentralized database in many locations around the world?

Comment: You can also read this article [How Can Blockchain Make Artificial Intelligence Better?](https://medium.com/@alinaparker11/how-can-blockchain-make-artificial-intelligence-better-f2a0477c7685).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Swarm intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_intelligence) is the term for systems where relatively simple agents work together to solve a complicated problem in a decentralized fashion.

In general, distributed computing methods are very important for dealing with problems at scale, and many of them embrace decentralization in a deep way. (Given the reality of hardware failure and the massive size of modern datasets relative to individual nodes, the less work is passed through a central bottleneck, the better.)

While there are people interested in doing computation on the blockchain, it seems to me like it's unlikely to be competitive with computation in dedicated clusters (like AWS).

Comment: Because of the simplicity of the agents, swarm intelligence is often not very decentralized in the specific sense of being "I/O bound, rather than compute-bound". That is, the amount of computation that agents do in between communicating is quite small. This is true, for example, in swarm intelligence systems such as Ant Colony Optimization and Particle Swarm Optimization. A system with agents performing more computationally-intensive operations is perhaps more akin to a blackboard architecture...

Comment: This does not answer the question "Has there been any attempts to deploy AI with blockchain technology?". SI doesn't necessarily use blockchain. Yes, distributed computing is important, but this also doesn't answer the question related to **blockchain** (not just distributed computing).

Answer (score 3):

I think the best example of AI being deployed on the blockchain is [SingularityNET](https://singularitynet.io/). They just had a successful token sell where they sold out of their AGI token which will be able to be used to essentially "pay" for AI tasks to be done for you. Various AI will be put on the network and able to interact and communicate with each other to get various tasks done. There are [some great videos online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFFHsmtQs6w) where Dr. Ben Goertzel explains this further. And here is a link to [their whitepaper](https://public.singularitynet.io/whitepaper.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the paper [Blockchain-Based Federated Learning in Medicine](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03080421/document) (2020), where the blockchain is used as a "federation" server for improving the parameters of local neural networks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of some works that use blockchains in [federated learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_learning) scenario for accountability, incentivize participants and so on.

Here's an example, [BlockFLA: Accountable Federated Learning via Hybrid Blockchain Architecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.07427) (2020), but there are probably many similar works around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a p2p framework to train with neuroevolution, it will have neat, hyperneat, and eshyperneat example experiments. AI developers will be able to fork and add any experiments they want.

It isn't a blockchain per sé but will have a dht for genes, champion nets, peers of course, and genomes. Neuroevolution training can be done in parallel so the population will be distributed evenly among peers, peers that finish early will help slower peers with their evaluations, and all peers will have a check on one of the nets they evaluated by a random peer to prevent malice and all peers will check the champion of each generation. Any peer that evaluates a net will be rewarded a token that is specific to the generation it helped train and will also download a copy of the champion net, later I plan to allow non training clients the ability to view performance of past champs and purchase them from the network, any peer with a token for the genome they purchase will receive part of the payment. This will not be proof of stake, it will be a proof of work where work is evaluating nets, since this needs to be checked by other nets so people don't just post phony fitness for genomes I'll be calling it proof of fitness.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the term you're looking for is federated learning. Check out [OpenMined](https://www.openmined.org/) project, [PySyft](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft) and [Tensorflow Federated](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated) libraries.