# Nature-inspired artificial intelligent methods for Blockchain?

Tags: algorithm, swarm-intelligence

I am working on the blockchain technology and I am not very familiar with the AI concept.

The proposal of this web page: (http://www.euraxess.lu/jobs/349354) opens a discussion about use of **nature inspired artificial intelligent methods for traceability chain decision in blockchain** technology as an **alternative to current consensus** mechanisms. It continues as follows:

> *"**It has been demonstrated** that using **traceability chain** is a more
>   effective method. In traceability chain, since the mechanism has to
>   trace related information among participant’s nodes across the entire
>   chain, the extraction and recognition of the data features plays a
>   crucial role in improving the efficiency of the process."*

However, it does not give any example to demonstrate **an instance** of this approach. So, I searched in google.scholar and any ordinary web pages to find only an instance similar to this approach since it has mentioned: "***It has been demonstrated*** that using **traceability chain** is a more effective method." (Please read the web page)

Is someone here familiar with this approach? And if yes, Is there any article/example to explain a more about this approach of consensus in blockchain? And what does exactly mean "traceability chain"? And also ingeneral, can we call this approach as a consensus? The text is not really clear to me.

**Please not that I have no idea about this proposal and just I'd like to know if it's practicable? or it's buzzwords?**

**Also, may this approach related to the approach that has been mentioned in this answer (Swarm Intelligence):** https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/1315/19910 **Or it is a different concept?**

Thanks for your help